# Как получить данные с полей нажатого DataGrid в коде

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Есть ДатаГрид с двумя полями, а так же событие двойной клик. Как именно с нажатого ряда получить данные.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="LVVid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MouseDoubleClick="LVVid_MouseDoubleClick">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="информация" Binding="{Binding Info}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Грузоподъёмность" Binding="{Binding CarCap}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Вот сам код C#

```
    private void LVVid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Сюда надо передать информацию с полей");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы навесили обработчик двойного щелчка на весь DataGrid, т.к. он сработает при клике по заголовку, по строкам, по пустому пространству под строками и т.д.

Чтобы решить вашу задачу, нужно навесить обработчик щелчка именно по *строке* DataGrid. Сделать это можно с помощью стиля:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LVVid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="информация" Binding="{Binding Info}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Грузоподъёмность" Binding="{Binding CarCap}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>,
```

Тогда код самого обработчика:

```
private void DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (DataGridRow)sender;
    if (!(row.DataContext is Data context)) return;
    MessageBox.Show(context.Info + " " + context.CarCap);
}
```

Здесь `Data` — тип объектов, отображаемых в DataGrid.

Comment: ругается на контекст http://prntscr.com/k2gd55

Comment: Используйте свежую версию языка. В более старом варианте замените строку `if (!(row.DataContext is Data context)) return;` на две: `var context = row.DataContext as Data; if (context == null) return;`